# sylius:install: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active

Tags: symfony, session, sylius

I'm installing sylius-standard.

When i run the cmd:
$ app/console sylius:install

Step 3 of 4. Shop configuration return this error:

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session modu
  le's ini settings at this time

php.ini -> session.auto_start = 0

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: me too but in the previous step

Comment: @Matteo check the answer posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faced same problem, and I got this fixed as,
observe the session property at `app/config.yml` at sylius installation time,

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %sylius.locale% }
    secret:          %sylius.secret%
    /****************
    *Other pramaters*
    *****************/
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
```

now change the `session` as

```
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    handler_id:  ~
```

Then , re-run command (mine solved when I re-run command after this config). Done.

If this doesn't solve your problem. Try changing your php.ini settings to `session.auto_start = 0`.

Comment: @Joost. You're welcome and if this has solved your issue then why not accept this as your answer ( clicking the right).

Comment: Hi @Joost! Yes, is solve for me also! Upvote for you